# Video at YouTube mobile website in WebView doesn't work - Android

Tags: android, youtube, webview

In my WebView I'm loading YouTube official website:
http://m.youtube.com/index?desktop_uri=%2F&gl=US#/

I want the user to be able to choose a video and simply watch it. The WebView doesn't do it so I thought that maybe I should run an intent to youtube app. 
First, I had to export the videoID from the link.

I tried this code, but it doesn't match the link..:

```
public class BrowserClient extends WebViewClient {    
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {       
            //Check if YouTube video link
            Log.d("WBC", "loading link: " + url);
            String youTubeLink = "http://m.youtube.com/index?desktop_uri=%2F&gl=US#/watch?xl=xl_blazer&v=";
            if (url.startsWith(youTubeLink)){      
                Log.d("WBC", "This is a YouTube link: " + url);
                 view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(String.format("http://www.youtube.com/v/%s", url.substring(youTubeLink.length(),url.length())))));
                  return true;
            }

            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this code, it works in mine apps perfectly.

```
            String sPath = "urlGoesHere";
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(sPath));
            startActivity(i);
```